# How do I display only the non empty or non null fields from a django a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model called Address and it has about 7 different fields. The corresponding form for this model is completely optional and the user may fill in either all 7 fields or just 1 field or none of the fields. There are no required fields here.

Now, if the user has filled only the city and country field, how would I in my class method fetch only those fields and then display it properly in the template?

This is the closest I've come to achieving what I want:

```
class Address(models.Model):
    address_name = models.CharField(...)
    line1 = models.CharField(...)
    line2 = models.CharField(...)
    line3 = models.CharField(...)

    city = models.CharField(...)
    state = models.CharField(...)
    zipcode = models.CharField(...)

    country = models.CharField(...)
    def get_fields(self):
        values = []
        for field in Address._meta.fields:
            if field.name in ('line1', 'line2', 'line3', 'city', 'state',
                              'postcode', 'country'):
                if field.value_to_string(self):
                    values.append(field.value_to_string(self))
       return values
```

In my template:

```
{% for field in address.get_fields %}
    {{field}}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% else %}.{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Now this achieves almost what I want, but in one of the test cases, if only one field has been filled out (for ex: only country was filled), it prints:

`, US.`

How do I make it say only `US` instead. Basically, the address format I want is:

```
{{line1}}, {{line2}}, {{line3}}, {{state}} - {{zipcode}}, {{country}}.
```

Is this kind of formatting possible at all with the way my model currently is? I even tried using `{% if %}` before each variable, but, then again, the commas don't sit well. What are my options here?

Comment: It looks like your method should work. Maybe one of the other fields is whitespace? _e.g._: `' '`.

Comment: I agree with @perfect5th so basically try with: `field.value_to_string(self).strip()`